# Why isn't there a music area?

Tags: discussion

What I mean by this is an area where people can ask questions about music on a non-technical level.
I know there's an area for music *theory* and performance but what I'd like is an area where general questions can be asked.

For example:

- What is the song 'free falling' by Tom Petty about ?
- Is there a definative list of different recordings of 'house of the rising sun' ?

Comment: You might want to check out the [Music Fans](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans) proposal and possibly others on Area 51.

Comment: @hims056 - noted. Before today I had no idea Area 51 existed !

Comment: Even if there were such a site, your first question would probably get closed as primarily opinion based, and the second as either too broad as it's asking for a list or as a request for an external resource.

Comment: I disagree that the first question is opinion based. Many artists (not all) are 'on record' explaining what the songs are about. In the case of old songs (e.g. English folk music standards), their meanings are a matter of historical record.

Comment: @Pat They try to keep its existence quiet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, if there isn't one it means:

- No one thought of it creating the site;
- Someone did, but there is no interest in it. There was a try-out, but it failed. There are not enough questions / low quality.

In all those cases, it is up to you to suggest a new site on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com). Even if a proposal failed the first time, just give it another try if you think the time is right now. You might want to look in the previous try, and check where it went wrong to prevent failure again.

In this case, like PeterJ already said, there is already a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans). So go there and be a early member of the community.